# How to make Maven Versions Plugin update-parent goal work with multi-module project

Tags: java, maven-3, parent, multi-module, versions-maven-plugin

I'm using version `2.1` of the `versions-maven-plugin`.

I have a source tree like the following:

```
+-- JavaProjects
    +-- customs-deployment-support
        +-- pom.xml
    +-- pom.xml     (a.k.a. base-parentpom)
+-- Projects 
    +-- customs-template
        +-- pom.xml
    +-- customs-ear-template
        +-- pom.xml
    +-- customs-rpm-template
        +-- pom.xml
    +-- customs-site-template
        +-- pom.xml
    +-- pom.xml     (a.k.a. customs-parentpom)
```

Now above, the `<parent />` for the `customs-template` project is `customs-deployment-support`.  The `<parent />` for all the other `customs-*-template` projects is `base-parentpom`.

Note: the `customs-parentpom` is just an "aggregator" and is not the real parent for any customs module, but it does declare each `customs-*` project as a `<module />` in its `<modules />` section.

For `SNAPSHOT` version builds this works great.

Now, I want to move to `versioned` artifacts where each artifact's version signature is something like `x.x.x_yyyyMMddhhmm_nn`.

So, now I want to employ the `versions-maven-plugin` to build the `customs-parentpom` (or "aggregator" `pom.xml`)

I use Jenkins for builds.  So I configure a pre-step to jigger the versions within the `<parent />` section of each customs project with something like:

```
mvn versions:update-parent
```

I want it to find the latest upstream artifacts (i.e., `base-parentpom` and `customs-parentpom`) available in Nexus.

But it fails with...

```
[ERROR] The build could not read 4 projects -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.etse:etse-customs-template:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ETSE-trunk-AllCustoms/workspace/customs-template/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find com.etse:etse-customs-deployment-support:pom:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT in http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of jboss-public-repository-group has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 5, column 11 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.etse:etse-customs-ear-template:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ETSE-trunk-AllCustoms/workspace/customs-ear-template/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find com.etse:etse-parentpom:pom:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT in http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of jboss-public-repository-group has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 5, column 10 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.etse:etse-customs-rpm-template:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ETSE-trunk-AllCustoms/workspace/customs-rpm-template/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find com.etse:etse-parentpom:pom:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT in http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of jboss-public-repository-group has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 5, column 10 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.etse:etse-customs-site-template:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ETSE-trunk-AllCustoms/workspace/customs-site-template/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find com.etse:etse-parentpom:pom:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT in http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of jboss-public-repository-group has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 5, column 10 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

Consider that I never want Jenkins to produce a `SNAPSHOT` version artifact in the above case.  I realize that the SNAPSHOT is not available in the local .m2 repository.  Do I (really) need one in order for the versions plugin to resolve correctly?

What am I doing wrong?  Is it even possible to do what I'm trying to do?  I'm willing to share pom.xml files if that will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was just a misunderstanding on my part.  If you employ a multi-module setup, you need to make sure that when you check-out your source, in order to build a module it must be able to trace its path back to a `parent` (via `<relativePath />`).

I was checking out a module, but not its parent; therefore I was getting the the `non-resolvable parent POM` errors.

So, in order for the reactor to do its part, you need to define all modules in the aggregator (and/or parent) `pom.xml`.

Then you can build a single (or multiple) modules (projects) like so

```
mvn clean install --projects <project1>,<project2> --amd
```

Comment: How did you handle the situation where you are releasing projects ( ex: customs-ear-template, lets assumes its parent is one of the project in JavaProjects). Assuming current JavaProjects version is 0.0.4-SNAPSHOT and in customs-ear-template you want to get 0.0.1 release, I don't think using versions:update-parent would work for 0.0.1 release for Projects (as it'll build a 0.0.3 artifact of customs-ear-template than building a 0.0.1 release artifact jar/war etc files). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25918593/interesting-maven-questions-pom-types-and-how-to-handle-maven-parents-uncl